# Yii2: delete records from junction table beforeSave/afterSave

Tags: activerecord, yii2, before-save

I'm trying to delete records from a junction table.
When `frequentie` is 2 (daily) I use a junction table to connect the `planning_id's` with the `dagen_id's`. But when the `frequentie` get's updated to weekly by example, I need to delete all those `planning_id's` from the junction table.

This is what I tried so far:

```
 public function beforeSave($insert)
    {
        if (parent::beforeSave($insert)) {
            $this->gewijzigd_op = new \yii\db\Expression('NOW()');
            $this->gewijzigd_door = Yii::$app->user->id;
            if ($this->getOldAttribute('frequentie') != $this->frequentie) {
                if ($this->getOldAttribute('frequentie') == 2) {
                    PlanningDagen::deleteAll(['planning_id' => $this->planning_id]);
                }    
            }
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Using:

```
$query = new \yii\db\Query();
                    $query->createCommand()->delete('planning_dagen', ['planning_id' => $this->planning_id)->execute();
```

instead of:

```
PlanningDagen::deleteAll(['planning_id' => $this->planning_id]);
```

Doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it using `afterSave`:

```
public function afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes) {
    parent::afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes);
    if (!$insert) { // since $insert is false, a database update happend instead of an insertion
        if ($changedAttributes['frequentie'] == 2 && $this->frequentie != 2) { // $changedAttributes is an array which holds the attribute-values from BEFORE the update, so you can compare them with $this (active record).
            PlanningDagen::deleteAll('planning_id = :id', [':id' => $this->planning_id]);                       
        }
    }
}
```